# Freemarker StringTemplateLoader

Tags: java, freemarker

I am trying to load some Freemarker templating from the DB using stringLoader and executing them through template.process, but here is the problem, freemarker stuff like <#if... is executing but when I try to execute assign JspTaglibs it breaks.

Here is a simple example:

From the DB I get <#assign bean=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld]>, which i put in a in StringTemplateLoader. I create configuration, template.. so far everything is working. When I do template.process(data, out), the page reports:

*Starting output:FreeMarker template error: The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> JspTaglibs [in template "temp" at line 1, column 15] Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally null/missing, either specify a default value with myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthessis: (myOptionVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionVar.foo)?? The failing instruction (FTL stack trace): ---------- ==> #assign bean = JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/s... [in template "temp" at line 1, column 1] ---------- Java stack trace (for programmers): ---------- freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...] at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:98) at freemarker.core.DynamicKeyName._eval(DynamicKeyName.java:87) at freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:111) at freemarker.core.Assignment.accept(Assignment.java:106) at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:265) at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:243) at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:277) at org.apache.jsp.test5_jsp._jspService(test5_jsp.java:109) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2440) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2429) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)*

Scenario that I have is that I have some code stored in the database and I would like to execute it by freemarker during template.process().
Is that even possible, and if it is, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `JspTaglibs` is not a core FreeMarker feature, but something that the `FreemarkerServlet` puts into the data-model, and something that requires Servlet environment and a HTTP request (as JSP requires that). Out of the box, there's no way to separate this feature from the `FreemarkerServlet`. However, maybe you can extend it so that you can still use it for your purpose. Most of the magic happens inside `createModel`, where among others, it adds `JspTaglibs` to the data-model.

It might also useful to know that FreeMarker (and thus `FreemarkerServlet`) can load templates directly from the database, if you give it a such `TemplateLoader` implementation through the FreeMarker `Configuration`. If all you want is serving templates from the database instead of where Struts traditionally stores them, you just need to provide the proper `TemplateLoader`.